# NodeJS Sequelize model options.timestamp generating extra columns in MSSQL

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am currently new to NodeJS and Sequelize but I am currently trying to populate my MSSQL database by building models using Sequelize, and calling the db:migrate Sequelize-cli command.

The problem I am running into is that the timestamps option within my models get ignored and timestamp columns (createdAt and updatedAt) get generated in the database.

Here is a sample of my model:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      userID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: "user_ID",
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: "username",
        allowNull: false
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: "password",
        allowNull: false
      },
      dateCreated: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: "date_created",
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: "users",
      timestamps: false
    }
  );
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // No associations
  };
  return User;
};
```

I have tried passing in

```
{
  tableName: "users",
  timestamps: false
}
```

and

```
{
  tableName: "users",
  timestamps: true,
  createdAt: false,
  updatedAt: false,
  deletedAt: false
}
```

deleting all the tables, and executing db:migrate again, but the columns still appear.

Would appreciate any help /:

Thanks!